How to record Accounts Receivable Opening Balances in GNUCash
What is the process of recording opening Accounts Received balances in GNUCash?  If this involves use of "dummy sales invoices", how is the resulting "dummy income" cancelled out from P&L reports?

My first suggestion would be to simply use the New Invoice process in GnuCash to record the invoice with the true transaction date.  If you haven't yet run your P&L reports for that period, then GnuCash will have the correct information to produce your P&L report.  If you have already run your reports for the period that contains your invoice date (from your old finance system) then this particular invoice won't be reported in your next P&L report because you'll set the relevant reporting period dates in the GnuCash report options.
If for some reason the above process won't work for you, then an alternative strategy would be to:

Process a New Invoice as normal.


This will result (among other things) in a transaction being created that debits Accounts Receivable and credits your income account.


Process a Transfer Funds (Ctrl+T) transaction for the same amount as the invoice income.


You should specify the same income account as the Transfer to account and Equity:Opening Balances (or some other Equity account) as the Transfer from account (you may need to first tick the "Show Income/Expense" box to show the relevant accounts).

The second transaction will effectively reverse the income recorded by the first account, leaving zero net income to be reported in the P&L, but still a positive amount in the Accounts Receivable account associated with the invoice.
I'm not an accountant, but I'm reasonably sure that this process won't corrupt the fabric of the universe.  Wouldn't hurt to try it first in your Test database, though, before committing to transactions in your main working file.
